# Sending information to the memory controller

Tags: caching, memory, operating-system, kernel

I'm trying to find ways to send some information about the physical address to the memory controller. This data could be used for performing some functionalities before the address leaves the CPU. Could anyone help me with this? I'm open to suggestions which include research papers as well.

I could introduce some hardware structures (caches) at the memory controller to provide and store the information. But is there a better way which uses less resources?